# How to use bootstrap grid-layouts in rails loop, using different grid classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I need to make a grid, using rails loop. It should look like this:
[image]

Usually, without rails loop, I would do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I need to show in that grid my `tips` objects:

```
<% @tips.limit(3).each do |tip| %>
  <%= tip.title %>
<% end %>
```

as an example.

So, what is the best way to do it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Just did like this, but I don't know, whether it is a right decision:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="tip-big">
       <p><%= @tips[0].title %></p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="tip-medium">
           <p><%= @tips[1].title %></p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="tip-medium">
           <p><%= @tips[2].title %></p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```